# JavaScript Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to refactor this..

```
if(!my_var){
     var new_var=100;
}else{
     var new_var=my_var;
}
```

I know I could do something like

```
var new_var = my_var == false ? 100 : my_var;
```

But I'm sure I've seen it done cleaner.

Comment: Did you mean `var new_var = 100;`?

Comment: @Connor - Then the refactored version is not the same as the original, hence why I thought maybe it was a copy-paste error.

Comment: The refactored version seems to have come from another planet...

Comment: The more i look at it now. the more i get confused....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a little cleaner:

```
let new_var = my_var || 100;
```

If `my_var` is `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `NaN`, or `0`, return `100`, else return `my_var`.

Comment: @jahroy Ha, I knew I was going to forget one.

Comment: I usually go [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) to make sure I don't forget one... (or link to it)

Comment: I thought that would be it :) No Problem. @user933791

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the normal way?

```
var newVar = myVar ? myVar : 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_var = (!my_var) ? 100 : my_var;
```